# Reading XML file - strange PHP object notation

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML file simillar to this :

```
<information version="2">
<currentTime>2014-06-06 17:28:16</currentTime>
<result>
<name>Mark</name>
<surname>Smith</surname>
</result>
```

I read it with php function and parse it to the object with function, like this:

```
function parse_data($data){
    $return_data['currentTime'] = $data->currentTime;

    $return_data['name'] = $data->result->name;
    $return_data['surname'] = $data->result->surname;

    return $return_data;
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($link));
$object = parse_data($xml);
```

Then, when I echo it on the screen, to check how it look:

```
//json_encode($xml);
{
  "@attributes":{"version":"2"},
  "currentTime":"2014-06-06 17:28:16",
  "result":{"name":"Mark","surname":"Smith"}
}

//print_r($xml);
SimpleXMLElement Object ( 
  [@attributes] => Array ( [version] => 2 )
  [currentTime] => 2014-06-06 17:56:30
  [result] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
      [name] => Mark
      [surname] => Smith
  )
)




//json_encode($object);
{
  "currentTime":{"0":"2014-06-06 17:28:16"},
  "name":{"0":"Mark"},
  "surname":{"0":"Smith"}
}

//print_r($object);
Array ( 
  [currentTime] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 2014-06-06 17:52:50 )
  [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Mark)
  [surname] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] =>  Smith )
)
```

What is wrong with my code? He seems to read the informaton in xml file as array? Because of this strange notation I cannont operate on this data normally.

It also behave like this:

```
echo json_encode($object['name']);  will give ->   {"0":"Mark"}
echo $object['name'];               will give ->    Mark
```

Can anybody help me? What am I doing wrong?

I want my $object to look like this:

```
//json_encode($object);
{
  "currentTime":"2014-06-06 17:28:16",
  "name":"Mark",
  "surname":"Smith"
}
```

Edit1: added print_r values

Comment: you're dealing with a simplexml object. EVERY node in a simplexml tree is an object, even if it only ever could contain one item. simplexml doesn't have a DTD to define the structure, so it builds an open-ended structure that can handle ANY xml document. so `$xml->name` is going to be an array of possible values, even if it only ever has one item in it.

Comment: In order for you to get the output that you want you would have to change your XML or do some hoop-jumping. Both 'name' and 'surname' are children of 'result', and the result of `json_encode` is as expected. What do you get when you `print_r($object)`?

Comment: Array ( [currentTime] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 2014-06-06 17:52:50 )[name] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Mark) [surname] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Smith )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you have noticed the type returned by $someSimpleXMLNode is an object.  If you want the node value (as a string for example) use:

```
$return_data['currentTime'] = (string)$data->currentTime;
```

which is the same as doing

```
$return_data['currentTime'] = $data->currentTime->__toString();
```

etc

When you do

```
echo $data->currentTime;
```

the node is automatically coerced into a string (because echo only handles strings).  This is done (generally, in php) by the object's __toString method.